# How can I access a private shadowed constant from a base class?

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    Base.Title.Dump("Base");             // displays "Base Title"
    Child.Title.Dump("Child");           // displays "Base Title"

    Base baseClass = new Base();
    Base childClass = new Child();       // "InvalidOperationException" would be thrown
}

class Base {
    public const string Title = "Base Title";

    public string ClassTitle { get; set; }

    public Base() {
        Type type = this.GetType();

        type.GetFields()
            .First(item => item.Name == "Title")
            .GetValue(this).Dump();
    }
}

class Child : Base {
    private new const string Title = "Child Title";
}
```

An "InvalidOperationException" exception is thrown in Base constructor.

Comment: Maybe revisit the idea of this thing being a constant if the first thing a derived type tries to do is get rid of it.

Comment: A base class should have no knowledge of it's child classes.  If you are coding otherwise you violate the Open-Closed Principle.

Comment: I'm doing maintenance on old code and I'm trying not to touch the hundreds of child classes.

Comment: How can you access Base.Title.Dump("Base") a non static property without an instance? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Edited the question to add the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the derived class Title, you need to either make the child class' Title public
or rudely crack open its private members with something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine((type.GetFields(
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(item => item.Name == "Title"))
    .GetValue(this));
```

If you want the base class Title, then your line:

```
Type type = this.GetType();
```

is getting the derived type when you want the base type.

Try this instead:

```
Type type = typeof(Base);
```

Comment: This lead me to the right answer.  Since the Title field is public in the Base class but private in the Child class I have to also check for BindingFlags.Public fields.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(type.GetFields().First(item => item.Name == "Title")).GetValue(this);
```

Comment: You are correct. Thinking about it I would use a reado only property on the base class instead of a constant and pass the value for the property in via the base class constructor. Alternaively use a readonly field.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing it works just find if you don't do it via reflection.

```
Title.Dump();
```

Comment: It would display "Base Title" instead of "Child Title" when I instantiate a Child class

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx), GetFields() returns only public fields by default.
Try to use the overload with BindingFlags.

Comment: This is an overload of GetField(). If you prefer, you can use an overload of GetFields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the overload of GetFields that specifies private, static fields:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .First(item => item.Name == "Title")
            .GetValue(null).Dump();
```

That said, this is a very bad idea.  Consider using attributes to associate metadata rather than using reflection to access private constants.